# Ruby On Rails unexpected query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

```
      @stations = Station.joins(:boo_reports).where(boo_reports: {date: params[:from].to_date..params[:to].to_date.tomorrow})
```

every station has reports this query expected to return 1 report only for each station if the date from 1-5-2018 to 4-5-2018 but the result is each station return all report in it

Comment: You can use `@states = Station.includes(:boo_reports).references(:boo_reports).where(...)` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in the stations and do not care about the reports for them, you should be able to chain `.distinct`.

The reason you're getting multiple results is because your query can return multiple rows for each station, example:

```
# | Station | Report date
1 | A       | 2018-05-01
2 | A       | 2018-05-02
3 | B       | 2018-05-02
```